# Regarding Griffith quantum mechanics problem 2.47: Square double well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

[image]

[image]

I have a query regarding part b) of the question. I do not understand in particular why $E_1$ and $E_2$ will vary as a function of $b$. With my understanding of the double rectangular potential problem, the value of $E_n$ is discrete found by solving the time independent Schrodinger equation and is approximate to $$E_n +V_0 = (n^2\pi^2\hbar^2)/8ma^2,$$ which is independent of $b$, thus the graph should be a horizontal line for both $E_1$ and $E_2$.

Comment: What would the stationary states of a single particle look like if the wells were close together, what about if they were on opposite sides of the universe? Here's a hint, the description you give $\frac{n^2 \pi^2 \hbar^2}{8ma^2}$ is true for the case where the wells are touching. What would it be if the wells were infinitely far apart? In that case, a particle could only occupy one well at a time, so what would the energy levels be?

Comment: Using your hint, since a particle occupies only one wall at a time, as $b$ approaches infinity, then $E_1$ will be $n^2\pi^2\hbar^2/2ma^2$ since the width is now $a$, which is halved? Same goes for $E_2$, which will become $4n^2\pi^2\hbar^2/2ma^2$? Am i right?

Comment: Have you done part (a) of the question, where you sketch the ground state and first excited states of the trapped particle for $b=0$, and then try to account for tunneling through a progressively thicker barrier?

Comment: Yep I have done so, for b=0 inside the barrier the graph is sinusoidal then exponential decay outside the barrier. The ground state is an even function whereas the first excited state is odd.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the limits $ b \to \infty $ and $ b\to 0 $ separately.

In the limit $ b \to \infty $ the two wells are isolated from each other and the result is each particle does not interact with each other, the wave functions are localised within each wel.

As $ b $ is reduced, the wave function is no longer localised in either well, due to tunnelling and with $ b = 0 $ you only have one well now of width $ 2 a $.